# ElectronJS crashes on dialog.showOpenDialog(...)

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, electron

I'm trying to prompt an "open file" dialog box, and I found `dialog.showOpenDialog(...)` in the [electron docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog).

I've added this line to a few different projects now, with the result of crashing as soon as that line hits. I would see the file explorer dialog window open for a second, then it crashed. The console gives me no error message, the last thing it prints is `Promise { <pending> }`.

**What I've tried:**

- Adding `dialog.showOpenDialog(...)` to the [official vscode debugging](https://github.com/octref/vscode-electron-debug/tree/master/electron-quick-start) example, to see if it picks up any errors. It always crashes as soon as it reaches that line, with no error message.
- Removing my node_modules folder and reinstalling electron using `npm install electron --save-dev`
- Running the app using a global electron command `electron .`
- Uninstalling global electron using `npm uninstall -g electron` and using a local `npm start`
- Checking if my node packages are out of date using `npm outdate
- Running the app using `--disable-gpu` argument

I'm using Ubuntu 19.04, not a VM, but I also tested it on Ubuntu 18.04 in a VM.

**One interesting note** is that when I tried to use an html form button with a `type = file` to accomplish this same task, it also crashed as soon as the file explorer dialog box opened in the electron app. BUT it did work when I opened the html page in a regular web browser.

**Here's my main.js**

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let win

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  win.loadFile('index.html')

  // Open the DevTools.
  win.webContents.openDevTools()

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  win.on('closed', () => {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    win = null
  })

  const { dialog } = require('electron')
  console.log(dialog.showOpenDialog({ properties: ['openFile', 'multiSelections'] })) //*****THIS LINE HERE
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

**Here's my package.json**

```
{
  "name": "electron-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^7.1.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: [this](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/20380)?

Comment: Yes! That problem exactly :(

Comment: did you find a solution beside running the app outside of vscode console?